# How to compare two array list and extract the element in third array list that are not common in both

Tags: java

I have two arraylist that has some elements I am comparing the elements of both arraylists and trying to extract the elements in third arraylist that are not common in both lists.

This is what I have done so far:

```
public class Details
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
    {

      ArrayList<String> al1= new ArrayList<String>();
      al1.add("hi");
      al1.add("How are you");
      al1.add("Good Morning");
      al1.add("bye");
      al1.add("Good night");

      ArrayList<String> al2= new ArrayList<String>();
      al2.add("Howdy");
      al2.add("Good Evening");
      al2.add("bye");
      al2.add("Good night");

      //Storing the comparison output in ArrayList<String>
      ArrayList<String> al3= new ArrayList<String>();
      for (String temp : al1)
          al3.add(al2.contains(temp) ? "Yes" : "No");
      System.out.println(al3);

  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[No, No, No, Yes, Yes]
```

I don't want output in yes or no form I want elements in new array list that are no common in both lists.

Someone please let me know how can I achieve desired result. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 2):

First, please program to the `List` interface (instead of the `ArrayList` concrete type). You can also use `Arrays.asList` to shorten your initialization. I would then `stream()` each `List` - you want fo filter the stream for elements not contained in the other `List` and then add them to your third `List`. Something like,

```
List<String> al1 = Arrays.asList("hi", "How are you", "Good Morning", "bye", "Good night");
List<String> al2 = Arrays.asList("Howdy", "Good Evening", "bye", "Good night");
List<String> al3 = al1.stream().filter(s -> !al2.contains(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
al3.addAll(al2.stream().filter(s -> !al1.contains(s)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(al3);
```

Which outputs

```
[hi, How are you, Good Morning, Howdy, Good Evening]
```

**or**, without streams (so you can better understand the algorithm),

```
List<String> al3 = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : al1) {
    if (!al2.contains(s)) {
        al3.add(s);
    }
}
for (String s : al2) {
    if (!al1.contains(s)) {
        al3.add(s);
    }
}
System.out.println(al3);
```